# How to do login with hardcored data?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two text fields named **username**, **password** and a hard coded `array of objects` with userdata:

```
<form action="submitLogin()">
    <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Username</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="loginData.username">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Password</span>
        <input type="password" ng-model="loginData.password">
    </label>
    <p style="text-align:center"ng-hide=myflag>wrong credentials</P>
    <label class="item">
        <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Log in</button>
    </label>
</form>
```

And I have an array of object

```
$scope.userdata = [
    {username:"vipin",password:"sddfds"},
    {username:"vineeth",password:"vdsf"},
    {username:"vishnu",password:"sdfsdfsd"}
];
```

How do I login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

### Login.html

```
<form ng-submit="submitLogin()">
    <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Username</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="loginData.username">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Password</span>
        <input type="password" ng-model="loginData.password">
    </label>
    <p style="text-align:center"ng-hide=myflag>wrong credentials</P>
    <label class="item">
        <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Log in</button>
    </label>
</form>
```

### And Controller

```
function ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.userdata = [{
    username: "vipin",
    password: "sddfds"
  }, {
    username: "vineeth",
    password: "vdsf"
  }, {
    username: "vishnu",
    password: "sdfsdfsd"
  }];

  $scope.submitLogin = function() {
    var addToArray=false;
for(var i=0;i<$scope.userdata.length;i++){
    if($scope.userdata[i].username===$scope.loginData.username && $scope.userdata[i].password===$scope.loginData.password){
        addToArray=true;
    }
}
  if(addToArray == true)
    {
      alert("login Sucessfull.!");
    }
    else
      {
        alert("invalid.!");
      }
  };
}
```

Here is the codepen Link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKBpVd

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="submitLogin()">
 <label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label">Username</span>
  <input type="text" ng-model="loginData.username">
  </label>
<label class="item item-input">
   <span class="input-label">Password</span>
  <input type="password" ng-model="loginData.password">
</label>
  <p style="text-align:center"ng-hide=myflag>wrong credentials</P>
 <label class="item">
 <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit" ng- click=”login()”>Log in</button>
 </label>
```

JavaScript Code

```
 $scope.userdata=[{username:"vipin",password:"sddfds"}, {username:"vineeth",password:"vdsf"},{username:"vishnu",password:"sdfsdfsd"}];
 $scope.login=function(){
        var login=0;
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.userdata.length;i++)
        {
            If($scope.loginData.password==$scope.userdata[i].password &&   $scope.loginData.username==$scope.userdata[i].username){

           login=1
           }

         If(login==1)
         {
          alert(“login successfully”);
         }
 }
```

---